# Project Euler Problem 18: What mistake did I make in my code?

Tags: python, algorithm

https://projecteuler.net/problem=18

Given a triangle of integers, the problem is to find the maximum path sum from top to bottom (where all the numbers in the path must be adjacent).

I had an idea for an algorithm: starting at the very top, calculate the sum of the left and right paths (left all the way down, and right all the way down), if the left sum is greater, jump to the left-adjacent number, if the right sum is greater, jump to the right-adjacent number, repeat the algorithm starting from the current number, and so on until you get to the bottom row.

```
triangle = ['75', '9564', '174782', '18358710', '2004824765', '190123750334', '88027773076367', '9965042806167092', '414126568340807033', '41487233473237169429', '5371446525439152975114', '701133287773177839681757', '91715238171491435850272948', '6366046889536730731669874031', '046298272309709873933853600423']

maximumPath = [75]
maxSum = 75 #Start it with the starting element of the triangle.

def triNum(row, index): #Returns the number at given row, number in row
    return(int(triangle[row][2*index:2*(index+1)])) #Nota bene: returns an integer.

def options(row, index): #Rows start at 0, index starts at 0
    return(triNum(row+1, index), triNum(row+1, index+1))

def criticalPathSum(startRow, startIndex, direction):
    critPath = []
    if direction == 'left':
        directionNum = 0
    else:
        directionNum = 1
    sum = triNum(startRow, startIndex) #Starting sum of left and right paths is just the number at the start of both paths.
    for i in range(startRow + 1, len(triangle)):
        startIndex += directionNum
        sum += triNum(i, startIndex)
        critPath.append(triNum(i, startIndex))
        #print(triNum(i, startIndex + directionNum))
    return(sum, critPath)

pathIndex = 0
for row in range(0, len(triangle)-1):
    print('These are my options: ' + str(options(row, pathIndex)))
    print('Left Sum: ' + str(criticalPathSum(row, pathIndex, 'left')) + ', ' + 'Right Sum: ' + str(criticalPathSum(row, pathIndex, 'right')))
    if criticalPathSum(row, pathIndex, 'left') > criticalPathSum(row, pathIndex, 'right'):
        maximumPath.append(triNum(row + 1, pathIndex))
        print('Left. ' + str(triNum(row + 1, pathIndex)))
    else:
        print('Right. ' + str(triNum(row + 1, pathIndex + 1)))
        pathIndex += 1
        maximumPath.append(triNum(row + 1, pathIndex))
    maxSum += triNum(row + 1, pathIndex)
    print('_______________________________')
    print('\n')
print(maximumPath)
print(maxSum)
```

The answer is 1067, but I get 883. This is the maximum path, according to the algorithm:

```
[75, 95, 17, 35, 82, 75, 7, 16, 80, 37, 91, 17, 91, 67, 98].
```

Comment: The answer is not 1067.

Comment: From your description, I'd guess that there's not necessarily a problem with your code, but with your algorithm. For example, try the triangle `[20], [15, 18], [20, 50, 13]`. From your description it sounds like your algorithm would produce the result 85, when it should be pretty easy to see that the answer should be 88.

Comment: well you need to create all the path from top to bottom , ie create a tree structure where each node is adjacent element of the previous node. it will creaate a binary tree, parse through it you will get the max result,  this is actul result `1074 = 75+64+82+87+82+75+73+28+83+32+93+73+58+78+91`

Comment: if you want help with code or logic [go through this](https://github.com/zmetcalf/Maximum-Path-Sum-I/blob/master/Maximum-Path-Sum-I.py)

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is wrong: in a triangle like

```
   1
  1 4
 1 4 1
9 1 4 1
```

it is too tempted by the `9` (always going left) to see the optimal `1+4+4+4` = `13` route.

Comment: the goal is to find the max result, so going through maximum of adjacent element in next layer won't guarantee the maximum result, so one need to travese through all the node, created using binary tree

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many wrong algorithms that the test data was designed to defeat.  You chose what is called a "greedy" algorithm, one that takes the maximum value for any single step, without considering long-term characteristics of the problem.

Rather, you need to work from the bottom of the triangle upward.  At each juncture, note which of the two paths gives the maximum sum to the bottom of the triangle, and record that as the optimum result from that node.  When you hit the apex, you will have the desired answer as the larger of the two elements underneath.

For instance, given the triangle

```
   1
  2 1
 2 1 9
1 2 1 9
```

your algorithm will be greedy and take the path 1-2-2-2; the lower choice of a `1` in row two cuts off that branch from the short-sighted logic.

Rather, you need to build up the totals from the bottom, taking the best of two paths at each node:

```
   20
  6 19
 4 3 18
1 2 1 9
```

In case this isn't clear enough ...
the bottom row has no further choices; each value is its own best path to the end.  For the row above, let's go right to left, considering each value and its two "children":

```
 2 1 9
1 2 1 9
```

The `2` has two values below, `1` and `2`.  Obviously, the `2` is better, so the best path from there is 2+2 = 4.
The 1 likewise has a `2` and `1` below; again, the better path is 1+2, giving 3.
The `9` has children of `1` and `9`; we choose 9+9=18.  The rows now appear as

```
   1
  2 1
 4 3 18
1 2 1 9
```

Now we move up one row, cosindering the two choices for `2 1` there.
The `2` has `4` and `3`; the `1` has `3` and `18`.  Again taking the higher value in each case and adding the node value, we get 2+4 = 6 and 1+18 = 19:

```
   1
  6 19
 4 3 18
1 2 1 9
```

Finally, the top node chooses the larger value of 19, giving a total of 20 along the path 1-1-9-9.

Got it?

Answer (score 1):

```
listOfLists = [
          [75],
          [95, 64],
          [17, 47, 82],
          [18, 35, 87, 10],
          [20, 4, 82, 47, 65],
          [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34],
          [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67],
          [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92],
          [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33],
          [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29],
          [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14],
          [70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57],
          [91, 71, 52, 38, 17, 14, 91, 43, 58, 50, 27, 29, 48],
          [63, 66, 4, 68, 89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31],
          [4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23]]


for i in range(len(listOfLists) - 2, -1, -1):
    for j in range(len(listOfLists[i])):
        listOfLists[i][j] += max(listOfLists[i+1][j], listOfLists[i+1][j+1])

print(listOfLists[0][0])
```

The bottom - top approach and it gets the right answer according to PE.
Thanks!